# Не добавляются значения в таблицу

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

Я пытаюсь добавить данные в таблицу test4, но они не добавляются. Ошибок никаких не выводятся. `

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    
                     user="root",         
                     passwd="0000",
                     db="test") 

conn.set_character_set('utf8') 
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("USE test")

data = [
  ('Jane', '12'),
  ('Joe', '12'),
  ('John', '145'),
]
stmt = "INSERT INTO test4 (Название, Дата_1) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.executemany(stmt, data)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Спустя кучу потраченного времени был найден ответ. И он оказался как всегда прост. В код нужно дописать conn.commit().